# Wipe temp folder/files for .net

Tags: c#, .net, directory, temporary-files

Let say I have some Sites running on my IIS.

When I want to remove the temp folder in this path C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files, I found that all temp files for the sites are stored in one folder called 'Root'. And all temp files from different sites seem like mixed up together and they're having weird folder name.

Then if I want to clear all temp data for a specific website only, how do I do that? How do I know which one belong to which website?

Comment: Why? Just delete all - they'll be recreated when necessary...

Answer (score 0):

I would not worry about which site they're for. Iterate over all of them and delete the ones older than some threshold. If you delete any that are for pages still in use, they'll get recreated as needed.

If you need to clean temp also remember .NET can create temp files in other locations too:

> C:\Windows\Temp
>
> C:\Documents and Settings\%COMPUTERNAME%\ASPNET\Local Settings\Temp\